MDX Custom member not using context
I have the below query which seems to be ignoring this member [Parent Matter Open Date].[Week Range].currentmember. When I replace this with [Parent Matter Open Date].[Week Range].&[20240909] it works. So the calculated member seems to not be able to use the Week Range context.
With
set [openDateRange] as [Parent Matter Open Date].[Week Range].&[20240909]

member measures.prodlastweek as sum({null:linkmember([Parent Matter Open Date].[Week Range].currentmember,[Production Date].[Week Range]).lag(1)},[Measures].[Amount - Production])
member measures.billingslastweek as sum({null:linkmember([Parent Matter Open Date].[Week Range].currentmember,[Production Date].[Week Range]).lag(1)},[Measures].[Amount - Billed])
member measures.include as sum(iif((isempty(measures.prodlastweek) or abs(measures.prodlastweek) < 1) and (isempty(measures.billingslastweek) or abs(measures.billingslastweek) < 1), 1, null))

set [matters] as nonempty(exists(existing [Matter].[Parent Matter].[Parent Matter],,"Parent Matter Distinct Count"),measures.include)

select
{
measures.[Matter - Estimate]
,measures.include
}
on columns,
{
nonempty(
{[Parent Matter Open Date].[Week Range].&[20240909]}
* [matters]
,{[Measures].[Parent Matter Distinct Count]})
}
on rows
From [cube]

I have tried using the existing statement in various places but either get errors or does nothing.
